# finishing up the onSubmit to create GraphQL mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, mutation

I'm just trying to complete the mutation to make it able to add a review. The graphql component works when I use the GraphQL queries, but I can't get it to work in the front end with React. wondering what I'm missing. I know i have to do something more on the onSubmit method in the form area but I keep getting errors.

I created a submitCreateReview function but I'm just getting the errors on the graphql side that

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$author" of required type "String!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

index.js:63 [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$rating" of required type "Int!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
index.js:63 [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$comment" of required type "String!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
index.js:68 [Network error]: Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
```

I'm using this [tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/blog/tutorial-render-props-in-react-apollo-2-1-199e9e2bd01e/) for help but not really getting anywhere:

```
class CreateReview extends Component {

    constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        author: '',
        rating: '',
        comment: ''
    };
}

submitCreateReview(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onCreateReview({
        variables: {
            author: this.state.author,
            rating: this.state.rating,
            comment: this.state.comment
        }
    });
}
render() {
    return <div className="create-review">
        <h3>Write a Review</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitCreateReview.bind(this)}
            }}>
            <label>Rate Your Experience</label>
            <div className="create-review__stars">
                <input id="_create_review_ratings"
                    value={this.props.rating}
                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ rating: e.target.value})} /><StarIcon />
            </div>
            <label htmlFor="create-review__author">Author</label>
            <input
                id="create-review__author"
                value={this.props.author}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({author: e.target.value})}
                 />
            <label htmlFor="create-review__comment">Review</label>
            <textarea
                id="create-review__comment"
                value={this.props.comment}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({comment: e.target.value})}
                />
            <button>Add Review</button>
        </form>
    </div>;
 }
}

const createReviewMutation = gql`
mutation createReview(
    $author: String!,
    $rating: Int!,
    $comment: String!,
) {
    createReview(
        author: $author
        rating: $rating
        comment: $comment
    ) {
        id
        rating
        author
        comment
        created_at
    }
}
`;


 export default function CreateReviewHOC(props) {
  return <Mutation
    mutation={createReviewMutation}
    update={(cache, { data: { createReview } }) => {
        const { reviews } = cache.readQuery({ query: props.getReviewsQuery });
        cache.writeQuery({
            query: props.getReviewsQuery,
            data: { reviews: [createReview].concat(reviews) }
        });
    }}
>
    {(submitCreateReview, { data }) => (
        <CreateReview
            {...props}
            onCreateReview={variables => submitCreateReview({ variables })}
        />
    )}
</Mutation>;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the errors?

Comment: I edited the code to show what I added and what errors I get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to ectract the variables on this line `onCreateReview={variables => submitCreateReview({ variables })}` it should be `onCreateReview={({variables })=> submitCreateReview({ variables })}`?